# Is it possible to get latest five google reviews from google places api?

Tags: google-api, google-places-api

I have developed a script to fetch and show google reviews using google places api.
It fetches five reviews but not the latest.

Does google places api returns 5 random reviews or latest 5 reviews ?

Thanks

Comment: Could you please show us an example of how you fetched the reviews? Maybe a jsfiddle. I've been trying to figure it out for a few days now and nothing. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as stated here : http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=2477

"It's the top 5 reviews shown on Google+ Local, which I believe are ranked by relevance/helpfulness. It's not possible to change the set of reviews that are requested."

Answer (score 2):

Places API only returns 5 by default, if you apply for the GMB API and you manage verifies locations you can access the reviews on the account but this only works if you’re approved for the API and you authenticate to the business; alternatively you can always copy/paste or use a third-party service to fetch like Reviewsmaker; but there’s no other way of getting more than 5 returned with Places API, same thing with Yelp who also restricts you from fetching more than a capped number.

Comment: Do you have a link to where it says it only returns 5 by default? I don't doubt you but I'd like to see it for myself. Also, is it possible to get less than 5?

Comment: On Google's official dev docs at https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/details "reviews[] a JSON array of up to five reviews.". You can use a third party API like https://www.reviewsmaker.com to pull more reviews if you need to.

Answer (score 0):

Simply you have an api that will always return the latest reviews from google map location.

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?place_id={Your Place ID}&fields=name,rating,reviews&key={GOOGLE DEV KEY}
```

Here is the response from that api.

```
{
  "html_attributions" : [],
  "result" : {
  "name" : "gathern app",
  "rating" : 5,
  "reviews" : [
     {
        "author_name" : "صالح وحيد Saleh Waheed",
        "author_url" : "https://www.google.com/maps/contrib/100946881376925963940/reviews",
        "language" : "en",
        "profile_photo_url" : "https://lh3.ggpht.com/-bgNhUmU_Ftg/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/-rLGfz7aAEk/s128-c0x00000000-cc-rp-mo-ba2/photo.jpg",
        "rating" : 5,
        "relative_time_description" : "in the last week",
        "text" : "Gathern is an online platform that helps people find vacation rentals and chalets in KSA.\n\nGreat team and great website.\n\nGathern.co",
        "time" : 1582015365
     },
     {
        "author_name" : "Hassan Raza",
        "author_url" : "https://www.google.com/maps/contrib/109666951306307815476/reviews",
        "language" : "en",
        "profile_photo_url" : "https://lh3.ggpht.com/-VrVSfhsRo28/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/9gJQWSdJ3TM/s128-c0x00000000-cc-rp-mo-ba3/photo.jpg",
        "rating" : 5,
        "relative_time_description" : "a week ago",
        "text" : "Great peoples and superb platform for booking online chalets.",
        "time" : 1581492666
     },
     {
        "author_name" : "Eman Alswailem",
        "author_url" : "https://www.google.com/maps/contrib/115734038039879616345/reviews",
        "language" : "ar",
        "profile_photo_url" : "https://lh4.ggpht.com/-xNiMOs2bD3A/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/tElDIT5zP78/s128-c0x00000000-cc-rp-mo/photo.jpg",
        "rating" : 5,
        "relative_time_description" : "2 months ago",
        "text" : "تطبيق ممتاز لحجز الشاليهات اون لاين",
        "time" : 1575659218
     },
     {
        "author_name" : "Hanan alnami",
        "author_url" : "https://www.google.com/maps/contrib/114513293972924581219/reviews",
        "language" : "ar",
        "profile_photo_url" : "https://lh6.ggpht.com/-BUEZWeWQhv4/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/7A8id3FGLQA/s128-c0x00000000-cc-rp-mo/photo.jpg",
        "rating" : 5,
        "relative_time_description" : "6 months ago",
        "text" : "تطبيق ممتاز دايم احجز منه شاليهات شكرا لكم",
        "time" : 1566223757
     }
  ]
},
"status" : "OK"
```

}