# is there anyway to limit display number to 2 reviews on google places using api

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm using webflow to display google reviews on my website using Google API, for now, everything ok
but instead display 5 reviews I would like to display only 2

I already a code to display the reviews but is there anyway to add in my code to display only 2 reviews?

```
<script>
    var map = document.getElementById('google-places');
    function initMap() {
        var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
        service.getDetails({
            placeId: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
        }, function (places, status) {
            if (status === google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
                reviewsArray = [];
                reviewsArray.push(places.reviews);
                for (var key in reviewsArray) {
                    var arr = reviewsArray[key];
                    for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
                        var review = arr[i];
                        var author = review.author_name;
                        var when = review.relative_time_description;
                        var comment = review.text;
                        var starNumber = review.rating;
                        var starPercentage = `${(starNumber / 5) * 100}%`;
                        console.log(starPercentage);
                        var profilePic = review.profile_photo_url;
                      //  console.log(author + ', ' + when + ', ' + comment + ', ' + rating + ', ' + profilePic);
```

document.getElementById('google-places').innerHTML +=
                            `
                    
    
        
            
                
            
            
                ${author}
                
                    
                        ☆☆☆☆☆
                        
                            ★★★★★

```
        </div>

    </div>
    <div class="review-content-wrapper">
        <div class="review-text">${comment}</div>
    </div>


    </div>
    </div>

                                `
                        }
                    }
                }
            })
        }
    </script>

<!-- Replace XXX with your key that you created at https://console.cloud.google.com -->
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&libraries=places&callback=initMap">
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears Google Reviews defaults to 5 reviews (source: [Is it possible to get latest five google reviews from google places api?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15719205/is-it-possible-to-get-latest-five-google-reviews-from-google-places-api)).

Could you use only the first two and ignore the last three?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this in your own code; it isn't API dependent; if you use Jquery or PHP for example you can loop through the array and only display the reviews with index 0 and 1 for example to only show the two and leave out the rest.